# How to check if a plot is visible under a tab panel?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on data visualization with R and shiny.

It takes some time to load my visualization and be able to provide plots under tab panels.

Ex. I made 3 tabs for box plot, bar plot, and bean plot

Taking time to visualize the result is understandable, but I am not sure how to check if the plot is visible so that users do not need to wait even though incProcess function reports the program is done.

First, I recorded the time to visualize and tried to delay some time, but it is very subjective to the data input, so I do not think that is a good solution.

Would you be able to provide me solution?

Thank you

I think I need a solution NOT to check if a code is done but the visualization is done.

Comment: By default shiny is lazy. A plot which currently isn't visible won't get rendered. To avoid this behaviour use `outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`. Also check shiny's [JavaScript events](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) if you really need to find out when an output was recalculated etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! So do you mean that if I set suspendWhenHidden = FALSE, it starts to render the plot as soon as I click the run button? Also, if I want to know as shiny finishes visualizing to enable inputs, how should I know the time?